# What is the IOMMU configuration used for the Intel machines?

Tags: linux, kernel, intel, iommu

In kernel boot options (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/boot-options.txt) I noticed the following option:

```
 iommu=[<size>][,noagp][,off][,force][,noforce]
    [,memaper[=<order>]][,merge][,fullflush][,nomerge]
    [,noaperture][,calgary]

  General iommu options:
    off                Don't initialize and use any kind of IOMMU.
    noforce            Don't force hardware IOMMU usage when it is not needed.
                       (default).
    force              Force the use of the hardware IOMMU even when it is
                       not actually needed (e.g. because < 3 GB memory).
    soft               Use software bounce buffering (SWIOTLB) (default for
                       Intel machines). This can be used to prevent the usage
                       of an available hardware IOMMU.
```

It mentions that iommu=soft is the default option for Intel machines and also mentions that it can be used to prevent the use of a hardware IOMMU.

So if this option is the default for Intel machines, do Intel machines not use hardware IOMMU or do they use hardware IOMMU + software bounce buffering by default?

Also, is there a way to see which IOMMU configuration is being used in the kernel after bootup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iommu=soft` option refers to a software workaround for systems that don't have IOMMU or where IOMMU is disabled. This workaround is called Software IO TLB (SWIOTLB). The SWIOTLB is a mechanism for systems without an IOMMU to be able to safely perform DMA operations to devices.

When `iommu=soft` is set (which is the default for Intel machines), the Linux kernel uses SWIOTLB by default. This does *not* mean that hardware IOMMU is not used *if it is* available, as the Linux kernel is designed to use the hardware IOMMU if it is available and functional, even if `iommu=soft` is set. The SWIOTLB mechanism is more of a fallback for when hardware IOMMU is not available.

To check the IOMMU configuration after bootup, you can use the command `dmesg | grep -i iommu`.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. What confused me was the sentence "This can be used to prevent the usage of an available hardware IOMMU". So to force using SWIOTLB when the HW IOMMU is present we need to use **iommu=soft** and **swiotlb=force**, right?